# Better sound with ALC883 possible?

Tags: 11.10, hda-intel

I have an onbaord-Soundchip:

Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) HD Audio Controller

Codec: Realtek ALC883

Codec: Realtek ALC268

The driver snd_hda_intel is installed and everything works "fine". But the output is really bad.

It sounds like an "old radio." In my "Windows-times" the sound was way better.

I play also with alsa mixer. Nothing became better. Alsa-version: 1.0.24.2

Is it possible to increase its quality?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the global equalizer for pulseaudio.  From a terminal or ALT+F2 run

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8 && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install pulseaudio-equalizer
```

It is located in Multimedia menu